# Write Zonal Statistics as table to an editable table in Python

Tags: arcpy, python, table, zonal-statistics, pandas

I am performing zonal statistics as table on many rasters (different years of data). I would like to write the result to a table that I can edit, so that I can rename the "SUM" column and left join the results to the previous table iteratively. This way, after my loop is done, I have columns: OBJECTID, SUM_2001, SUM_2002, SUM_2003, SUM_2004... as my resulting table.

How do I write my results to a table that lives in memory and is editable, as opposed to a file?

Answer (score 1):

I'd make use of the [in_memory](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm) workspace to store your table.

> ArcGIS provides an in-memory workspace where output feature classes
>   and tables can be written. Writing geoprocessing output to the
>   in-memory workspace is an alternative to writing output to a location
>   on disk or a network location. Writing data to the in-memory workspace
>   is often significantly faster than writing to other formats such as a
>   shapefile or geodatabase feature class. However, data written to the
>   in-memory workspace is temporary and will be deleted when the
>   application is closed.

esri's example:

```
import arcpy

table = arcpy.CreateTable_management("in_memory", "table1")
arcpy.AddField_management(table, "Field1", "TEXT", field_length=20)

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table, ["Field1"])
cursor.insertRow(["Hello World"])
```

Use [Alter Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/alter-field-properties.htm) for changing field names.

> Rename fields and field aliases, or alter field properties.

Comment: Thanks - for anyone else also wondering, this link probably will help, too: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm